# Hide <h3> when all ul>li of group does not contain filter term

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a small script that filters my ul with a nested ul inside of it. The only issue with my script is I want to hide the title of the nested ul if none of the li's contain the search term, but I am not sure how to go about checking the li's of each "group" as opposed to each li individually. The way it stands, it will display the title if it finds an li in the group matching the search term, but it will immediately turn around and hide the title if the same group contains an li that DOES NOT contain the search term. I know what I'm doing wrong, but I am not as skilled in jquery and cannot seem to visualize how to go about this.

Any help would be great. My code is below:

HTML:

```
<div id="sitemap">
         <h3>Hospital Data Solutions Interactive Site Map</h3>
         <hr/>
    <p id="header"><input type="text" placeholder="Filter Site Map"> - Use this field filter our list of databases: Search by Topic or Topic Subgroup</p>

    <ul id="toplist">
       <li class="group">
           <h3 class="sTitle">Available Beds - <a style="font-size:18px;">Go to Section</a></h3>
           <ul class="sublist">
           <li>General</li>
           <li>ICU</li>
           <li>CCU</li>
           <li>BICU</li>
           <li>SICU</li>
           <li>Other</li>
           <li>Hospice</li>
           <li>Total</li>
           </ul>
       </li>
       <hr/>
       <li class="group">
           <h3 class="sTitle">Discharges - <a style="font-size:18px;">Go to Section</a></h3>
           <ul class="sublist">
           <li>Medicare</li>
           <li>Medicaid</li>
           <li>Other</li>
           <li>Total</li>
           </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function(){

    $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){

        var searchText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $('.sublist>li').each(function(){

            var currentLi = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            if(currentLi.search(searchText) != -1){
            $(this).slideDown();
            $(this).closest('.group').children('.sTitle').show();
            } else { $(this).slideUp(); $(this).closest('.group').children('.sTitle').hide();}
        });     
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, select the `.sublist` elements instead of the `li`s.

Then iterate that collection using `.each()`, and use `.children()` to test each `li` like you currently are, except use `.filter()` instead of `.each()`. This will give you a collection as a result. If the collection is empty, there were no matches. If not, then there was a match.

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){
    var searchText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $('.sublist').each(function(i, sub){
        var matches = $(sub).children().filter(function(i, li) {
            return $(li).text().toLowerCase().search(searchText) != -1;
        });

        if (matches.length) {
            $(sub).slideDown().prev().show();
        } else {
            $(sub).slideUp().prev().hide();
        }
    });     
});
```

Now the `slideDown/Up` and `show/hide` are happening once per `sublist` instead of on every child `li`. And I just used `.prev()` to get back to the `h3` element.

Comment: Dang this works perfect. Thanks for helping me visualize/get over the mental hump of what should be going on here. I appreciate it. Marked you as correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be hiding those list items that don't match your search you're going to want to deal with them individually anyway, so I wouldn't abandon that approach.  So you just need a way to check to see if the term was found somewhere in the search of the nested list.  Here's what I might do to utilize what you already have.

After you capture the search term, loop through each of the sublists and set a flag to false; this will be where we capture whether there were any matches.  Then loop through that sublist's items, and if you find a match set the flag to true, showing or hiding the item as necessary.  Then, after you've checked all the items show or hide the heading based on that flag.  It might look something like this:

```
$('.sublist').each(function(){
  found = false;
  $(this).children("li").each( function() {
    var currentLi = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    if(currentLi.search(searchText) != -1){
      $(this).slideDown();
      found = true;
    } else {
      $(this).slideUp();
    }
  });
  if(found) {
    $(this).closest('.group').children('.sTitle').show();
  } else {
    $(this).closest('.group').css("list-style-type", "none");
    $(this).closest('.group').children('.sTitle').hide();
  }  
});
```

I added a css line to show/hide the header's disc to avoid having that hanging there if everything else disappears.  Hope this helps!  Let me know if you have any questions.